# Closing VS2008 with no files, no projects, no solution still wants to save a solution

Tags: visual-studio-2008

For some reason when I open an instance of VS2008 to view a single file say a web.config file even when I make no changes and close the file I can't close VS2008 unless I save a dummy solution. I have no files or projects in it so why can't I just exit the program? I have to either kill the devenv process or simply save the dummy Solution1.sln each time. It's not like that's onerous but is there a config setting somewhere that insists on saving the solution when you exit?

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just answer **no** or **cancel** if VS asks you to save the solution?

Comment: Of course you can, so +1. Visual Studio just creates a temporary solution you *might* want to save. It's an IDE after all, not a text editor.

Comment: No if you Cancel or say No it still leaves VS open.

Comment: Just tried it myself, and when I close VS2008 again after openng a single source file, it doesn't ask me to save anything.